# Is there a higher order chain rule such that $\frac{d^2 r}{ds^2}= \frac{d^2 r}{dx^2} \frac{d^2 x}{ds^2} $

Tags: calculus

I don't have much more to add the question is right there in the title. I just came across this in a long calculation that I'm working on. It would make everything easier if this were true.

Comment: What does $dr^2/ds^2$ mean?  I'm familiar with $d^2r/ds^2$ if that was your intention.

Comment: it could be a the derivative of a vector or the component of a vector with respect to the arc length. but really it is just assuming that r=r(s). r is a function of s.

Comment: To clarify: you are asking if there is a general rule of the chain rule for second order derivatives? In that case, define an operator $D$ such that $Df(x)=df/dx$. Prove that it is linear and notice that $Df(g(x))=DfDg$. What happens if you apply $D$ again?

Comment: @AndrewChin thanks. i edited it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ in order to find $\frac{d^2r}{ds^2}$. Starting off from $$\frac{dr}{ds}=\frac{dr}{dx} \frac{dx}{ds}$$

Differentiate wrt $s$ to get

$$\frac{d^2r}{ds^2}=\frac{dx}{ds}\left(\frac{d}{ds}\frac{dr}{dx}\right) + \frac{dr}{dx} \frac{d^2x}{ds^2}$$

Use the chain rule to get $$\frac{d^2r}{ds^2}=\frac{dx}{ds}\left(\frac{d^2r}{dx^2} \frac{dx}{ds}\right) + \frac{dr}{dx} \frac{d^2x}{ds^2}$$

Or equivalently, $$\frac{d^2r}{ds^2}=\left(\frac{dx}{ds}\right)^2\frac{d^2r}{dx^2}+\frac{dr}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}$$

For higher order derivatives, you can use [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: Thanks.  This helps a lot.